# How do I get broken glass out of my mop?

Tags: house-cleaning

Today my son knocked over a snow globe and broke it, glass and water everywhere. After I picked up the big pieces of glass and swept up the rest, I had to use my mop to get all the water up, which was full of tiny pieces of broken glass.
I have a microfiber spin mop, which is machine washable but I don't want to ruin my washer with all the glass.
Does anyone know how to get broken glass out of a mop?

Comment: I feel like this was answered in the movie _Joy_, which I believe was about the invention of this mop, but I don't remember the answer.

Comment: Hi Princess, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience here.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a long time ago that small shards of glass have to be collected with something disposable: paper (napkins, toilet paper, anything that has a chance to collect the shards), old rag which needs to be thrown away anyway etc.

We did the same mistake, to use something not disposable, and we decided that **safety** is more important. We had to throw away the (whatever we used instead of a mop - I do not remember, it was a long time ago).

Sorry for your losses, the globe and the mop.

Comment: +1 I looked on amazon and found replacement heads for "microfiber spin mop" for around $5, much cheaper than a visit to a doctor if one of those pieces of glass needs to be removed from a person, and if a person or pet accidentally swallows it, that could be life altering.